# Delphi 7 - Form1.Caption to display 2 different strings

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-7

My program when downloads some files it uses 2 labels to describe the procedure. one label displays ''Downloading'' and the other label displays the name of the file.

```
private
     MTemp : string;
     STemp : string;

    procedure GFilesThread.UpdateStatusLabel;
      begin
          Form1.Label1.Caption:=MTemp;
          Form1.Label2.Caption:=STemp;
      end;
```

I need to get my Form1.Caption display both. For example: 'Downloading file1.txt'. How do i do that?

```
Form1.Caption:= MTemp, '+', STemp;
```

or?

Comment: Not faster but reliable method is using `Format` function. In your example it will be `Form1.Caption:= Format('%s + %s', [MTemp, STemp]);` Read more about `Format` function.

Comment: @Abelisto: There's absolutely no need to use `Format` simply to concatenate two strings. `Format` carries a lot of overhead which in this case would simply be a waste of CPU cycles when the compiler will take care of concatenation with `+` with a lot less effort.

Comment: @KenWhite Absolutely agree with you. BTW It is only programmers decision what to use: faster or more readable code. For example in the code snippet like `for ...` or `while ...` or `until ...` i will never propose `Format` function :)

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry for some discussion. There are several cases. If your code will be executed 1-2-10 times at the session - use `Format` function to combine completed text. In other case (100-1000-10000 times) - it is very different question. For example: how to use memory block for many allocations.

Comment: @Abelisto: You can compare the two by looking at the generated assembly code in the CPU view. `Format` jumps through hoops, has to parse the format parameter to see what data types to expect, has to check the arguments to make sure they match that type, and raises an exception if they don't. Concatenation, OTOH, is done strictly by allocating space and copying; the compiler does the type checking, so there's no overhead at runtime needed to do so. Using `Format` even once when not needed is wasteful, and if you get in the habit you'll use it all over your code where it's not needed.

Comment: @KenWhite You can see above that I know about overhead of the `Format` function. I also mention that it is can be used only in the single, not in the multiple cycle algorithm. Lets remember the question: it is like "how to show some data in the MessageBox".

Comment: @Abelisto: No, it isn't. It's about how to concatenate two simple strings, and David answered it properly. Your advice in this case to use `Format` is simply wrong, and I've explained why. You choose not to listen, and that's fine. Fortunately for both of us, you don't work with me and I don't review your code. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's easy, try assign this one:

```
Mtemp + ' ' + Stemp
```

(`' '` - just space separator between two strings)

Comment: Thank u very much i used  Form1.Caption:= ('MyUpdater - Updater      ' + MTemp+ ' '  + STemp);

Answer (score 3):

Concatenate strings with `+`

```
Form1.Caption := MTemp + STemp;
```